# Spring Boot, implement login with encoded password

Tags: java, spring, hash, spring-security, authentication

I am developing a Java password manager using Spring Boot, Spring Sec, mySQL.
My login page works great, i have two kind of user: ADMIN and NORMAL.
Admin can create a new user, and when it happens, the new user will be persisted on db with the hashed password and a clear text username. My **webController** class below:

```
@Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@RequestMapping(value = { "/login" })
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/insertuser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String insertuser(ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.put("user", new User());
        return "insertuser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "insertuser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String insertuser(
            @ModelAttribute("user") User user, ModelMap modelMap) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);

        userService.addUser(user);
        return "home";
    }
```

And here we have the **SecurityConfig** class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled from user where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select usernameusr, role from userroles where usernameusr=?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin", "/getrole", "/getusers", "/insertuser").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout()
                .permitAll();   

        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
        }
}
```

On db the new user saved by the admin has the hash of is password.

username: anakin

password: $2a$10$.AVpjhbsVKfGtMxiKlTts.2yiiKB0gF7xu2lrL6o3iEWqIMDgM43.

password in clear text is:  *vader*

Now if i logout and try to login with the user credential anakin/vader i get a bad credential error.

How can i implement a correct login using the encoded password?
I know that we need to get the submitted clear password, apply the hash function and if it matches with the hash password on db the login conclude successfully, but how can i implement this approach?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
<title>PASSWORDMANAGER</title>

    <div th:replace="fragments/header :: header-css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/header :: header"/>

    <h1 style="text-align: center">
        <font size="20" color="blue">MAIPASSWORD HOME</font>
    </h1>


    <div style="text-align: center" th:if="${param.error}">
        <h1 style="color: red">Bad Credentials. Try again.</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center" th:if="${param.logout}">
        <h1 style="color: blue">Logged out.</h1>
    </div>
    <form style="text-align: center" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="username" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="password" name="password" value=""
                placeholder="password" />
        </p>
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
        </p>
    </form>
    <div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your configAuthentication call passwordEncoder at the end of your auth object, and pass in your autowired password encoder. This will automatically handle the encoding of the password and attempt the login with it.

Comment: Since you are already autowiring in a bcrypt password encoder, I would imagine this will error out since there is a bean already defined for your BCryptPasswordEncoder, try autowiring it in like you did in the webcontroller class, and just pass in the autowired variable into the function rather than doing that function.

Comment: now i get this error if i try to login with a user that has clear password on db 'Encoded password does not look like BCrypt ' than if i try to login with a user with hash password i get bad cred. error

Comment: Those two errors indicate that the bcrypt encoder is now working when you log in. You might want to try recreating the user and logging in at is again just in case the password was entered incorrectly. You may also want to ensure that when you created the user there was no other changes done to the password string before it was encoded. Just as an aside I'd also recommend using the same method of autowiring in the passwordencoder that you are when you encode the password rather than a function that creates a new instance of the bcrypt encoder.

Comment: @Artichoke In my application admin need to login to user account and admin has the encoded password.So is there a way for admin to bypass this password encoding while login???Please help me.ie,in my app there are two way of logging one by the user which happens normally by the clear text password which uses password encoding in spring boot and the other is by the admin where hashed password is used by admin and which needs to bypass the spring boot password encoding.

Answer (score 0):

okay, now all works. Adding the following code inside my **WebController** Java file.

```
 @Autowired
   private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
   String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);}
```

And inside my **SecurityConfig**

```
   @Autowired
   public PasswordEncoder BCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();}

  @Autowired
  public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth
 .jdbcAuthentication()
 .dataSource(dataSource)
 .passwordEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder()
 .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled from user where username=?")
 .authoritiesByUsernameQuery
 ("select usernameusr, role from userroles where usernameusr=?");
 })
```

Thank you so much Artichoke